# Map a json to another json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and json. I want to know how to properly map a Json (1) to another Json (2)?

I am getting a very nested Json from the API and I want to show just some information on a web page. To do this, I want to simplify that received json, I am doing it using a .map () function, but my second Json is still empty.

First Json

```
var data = {
  "Main": {
    "General": [
      {
        "Country": "ARGENTINA",
        "City": "Buenos Aires",
        "population": "2,891,082",
        "Area": "203 km",
        "HDI": "0.867",
        "Established": "2 February 1536 "
      }
    ],
    "Network": [
      {
        "Network Code": "11111",
        "Network Name": "e.g. 1"
      },
      {
        "Network Code": "22222",
        "Network Name": "e.g 2"
      },
      {
        "Network Code": "33333",
        "Network Name": "e.g. 3"
      }
    ],
    "Security": [
      {
        "robberies": "NONE",
        "thefts": "NONE"
      }
    ],
    "Language": [
      {
        "Language 1": "SPANISH_LATIN_AMERICA",
        "Language 2": "NONE",
        "Language 3": "NONE"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Browser": {
    "websites": [
      {
        "Website Class": "non-local",
        "Name": "wikipedia",
        "URL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buenos_Aires"
      }
    ],
    "Gov": [
      {
        "URL": "www.buenosaires.gob.ar"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Soccer Teams": {
    "dados": [
      {
        "Name": "Boca Jrs",
        "division": "1",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      },
      {
        "Name": "River Plate",
        "division": "1",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      },
      {
        "Name": "All Boys",
        "division": "2",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sacachispas",
        "division": "4",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My code

```
var newData = [{
  "Main infos": [],
  "Web":[],
  "Soccer Teams":[],
}]

newData['Main infos'] = data['Main']["General"].map((general) => {
  return {
      "Country": general["Country"],
      "City": general["City"],
      "population": general["population"],
  }
});
newData['web'] = data['browse'];
newData['Soccer Teams'] = data['Soccer teams']['dados'];

console.log(newData);
```

My desired result would be something like this Json

```
var data = [
  "Main infos": {
    "Country": "ARGENTINA",
    "City": "Buenos Aires",
    "population": "2,891,082"
  },
  "Web": {
    "websites": [
      {
        "Website Class": "non-local",
        "Name": "wikipedia",
        "URL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buenos_Aires"
      }
    ],
    "Gov": [
      {
        "URL": "www.buenosaires.gob.ar"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Soccer Teams": {
    "dados": [
      {
        "Name": "Boca Jrs",
        "division": "1",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      },
      {
        "Name": "River Plate",
        "division": "1",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      },
      {
        "Name": "All Boys",
        "division": "2",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sacachispas",
        "division": "4",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: There's no JSON there. Just JavaScript.

Comment: You like putting spaces in your Object property names? If you want dot access, do yourself a favor, don't put in spaces. Why not just use the data the way you got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const newData = {};

newData['Main infos'] = data.Main.General.map((general) => {
  return {
    Country: general.Country,
    City: general.City,
    population: general.population,
  };
});
newData.web = data.Browser;
newData['Soccer Teams'] = data['Soccer Teams'];

console.log(newData);
```

1. Be careful with the names of the properties of the object. They are case sensetive. 'Browser', 'Soccer Team'.
2. You structure is wrong:

```js
var newData = [{
  "Main infos": [],
  "Web":[],
  "Soccer Teams":[],
}]

var data = [
  "Main infos": {
    "Country": "ARGENTINA",
    "City": "Buenos Aires",
    "population": "2,891,082"
  },
// ...
]
```

You are defining an Array. But it should be an object.

```js
var data = {
  "Main infos": {
    "Country": "ARGENTINA",
    "City": "Buenos Aires",
    "population": "2,891,082"
  },
// ...
}
```

3. If you run your code you can fix most errors just reading error messages. So, learn how to run code and read those messages.
4. You don't need to initialize an object with properties placeholders. You are about to populate them rewriting them.

Answer (score 0):

It's just some Syntax errors. Note in your code that is wrote 'browse' and 'Soccer teams' instead of 'Browser' and 'Soccer Teams'. I made just little fixes. That might work well.

```
let newData = [];

newData['Main infos'] = data['Main']['General'].map((general) => {
  return {
    Country: general['Country'],
    City: general['City'],
    population: general['population'],
  };
});
newData['Web'] = data['Browser'];
newData['Soccer Teams'] = data['Soccer Teams'];

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is what you are looking for:

```js
var data = {
  "Main": {
    "General": [
      {
        "Country": "ARGENTINA",
        "City": "Buenos Aires",
        "population": "2,891,082",
        "Area": "203 km",
        "HDI": "0.867",
        "Established": "2 February 1536 "
      }
    ],
    "Network": [
      {
        "Network Code": "11111",
        "Network Name": "e.g. 1"
      },
      {
        "Network Code": "22222",
        "Network Name": "e.g 2"
      },
      {
        "Network Code": "33333",
        "Network Name": "e.g. 3"
      }
    ],
    "Security": [
      {
        "robberies": "NONE",
        "thefts": "NONE"
      }
    ],
    "Language": [
      {
        "Language 1": "SPANISH_LATIN_AMERICA",
        "Language 2": "NONE",
        "Language 3": "NONE"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Browser": {
    "websites": [
      {
        "Website Class": "non-local",
        "Name": "wikipedia",
        "URL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buenos_Aires"
      }
    ],
    "Gov": [
      {
        "URL": "www.buenosaires.gob.ar"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Soccer Teams": {
    "dados": [
      {
        "Name": "Boca Jrs",
        "division": "1",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      },
      {
        "Name": "River Plate",
        "division": "1",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      },
      {
        "Name": "All Boys",
        "division": "2",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sacachispas",
        "division": "4",
        "Flag": "NONE",
        "Address": "NONE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
var newData = {
  "Main infos": [],
  "Web":[],
  "Soccer Teams":[],
}

newData['Main infos'] = data['Main']["General"].map((general) => {
  return {
      "Country": general["Country"],
      "City": general["City"],
      "population": general["population"],
  }
});
newData['web'] = data['Browser'];
newData['Soccer Teams'] = data['Soccer Teams']['dados'];

console.log(newData);
```